# Bootstrap3 Popover showing at wrong place upon zoom in/out or resizing Browser window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I re-size windows of any browser by zooming-in or zooming-out. Popover is not updating position and showing at wrong place.

How do I change the placement/position of Bootstrap Popover upon re-sizing / zooming the browser's window.

please help me.

Comment: In general, Bootstrap doesn't support browser zooming: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browser-zooming

Comment: Are you using the `container` option of tooltips?